# npm not creating node_modules

Tags: npm

Steps to reproduce

1. Windows 11
2. Somehow break npm?
3. go to an empty directory and run `npm init -y`
4. run `npm install zod`

`node_modules` folder does not get created. I can't import zod. I have internet connection. For some reason there is `e_modules/zod` in the `package_lock.json`

- Node v18.18.0
- npm v9.8.1

Final `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "hello",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "zod": "*"
  }
}
```

Final `package-lock.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "hello",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 3,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "hello",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "zod": "*"
      }
    },
    "e_modules/zod": {
      "version": "3.22.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/zod/-/zod-3.22.4.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-iC+8Io04lddc+mVqQ9AZ7OQ2MrUKGN+oIQyq1vemgt46jwCwLfhq7/pwnBnNXXXZb8VTVLKwp9EDkx+ryxIWmg==",
      "extraneous": true,
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.22.5",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.5",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.22.5",
        "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.2.0",
        "@swc/core": "^1.3.66",
        "@swc/jest": "^0.2.26",
        "@types/benchmark": "^2.1.0",
        "@types/jest": "^29.2.2",
        "@types/node": "14",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.15.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.15.0",
        "babel-jest": "^29.5.0",
        "benchmark": "^2.1.4",
        "dependency-cruiser": "^9.19.0",
        "eslint": "^8.11.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
        "eslint-plugin-ban": "^1.6.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
        "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^7.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^2.0.0",
        "husky": "^7.0.4",
        "jest": "^29.3.1",
        "lint-staged": "^12.3.7",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
        "prettier": "^2.6.0",
        "pretty-quick": "^3.1.3",
        "rollup": "^2.70.1",
        "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
        "ts-morph": "^14.0.0",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "tslib": "^2.3.1",
        "tsx": "^3.8.0",
        "typescript": "~4.5.0",
        "vitest": "^0.32.2"
      },
      "funding": {
        "url": "https://github.com/sponsors/colinhacks"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If your "steps to reproduce" contain _questions_, they're not.

Comment: what do you mean